# Software to make a list of all files & folders on a disk with file hashes

Tags: windows-7, file-management, backup

Lately one of my hard drives died.

I managed to save some of the data before the event because of **S.M.A.R.T.** and **CrystalDiskInfo** which showed about 2k reallocated sectors.

Now I have about 6 TB of data and not even half of that to make a full backup.

Since most of the files are available on the internet, I decided to backup only files that are not (private) or are important.

In the event that one of my HDDs dies again, it would be nice to have a list of files that I accumulated over time since I will definitely forget many of them.

So **which** programs can make a list of files and folders?

Some of the features that the program I like to have are:

1. Recursive scanning so I can point to a folder as input
2. Save metadata like size and checksum

I could never be sure of the files that I have saved that they have not been corrupted.  That's why this time I want to also compute and save the hash for each file.

The size seems redundant if you have the hash, but if I have to download them again I can only check the hash only after the file is completely downloaded.

Files with hashes allows me to check over time the files are starting to get corrupted.

Until now I found:

- [CHK Checksum Utility](http://compressme.net/) which unfortunately doesn't save the size, even that is shown in interface and can't compare files with saved list
- [ExactFile](http://www.exactfile.com/) which does everything that I want except the file size

Are there any other programs that can do this?

I'm using Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your question, but aren't you wasting your time? A good backup solution (maybe cloud) is all you need, with the usual selection possibilities on what to back up (folders. file types, ...)

Comment: Well I don't think I'm wasting my time preparing for the inevitable hard drive failure, cloud means spending money, good internet connection which I don't have and privacy issues

Comment: One of my hard disks died in January. I spent ~800 EUR for disks, hardware and software to have a good backup strategy. Hard to beat with software only, really.

Answer (score 1):

Also I havn't used it in a long time, [HashCheck Shell Extension](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/) should do the trick.

For a picture is worth a thousand words,

[image]

Comment: How to save that data? It looks like a list only.

Comment: You can right click -> create checksum file. However if that's the list you wanted to save, I got your request wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got a complete understand of what you want, but I think this should work for you.

NirSoft's HashMyFiles - http://nirsoft.net/utils/hash_my_files.html

- Tiny, lean and fast hashing application
- Allows you to traverse through folders and entire disks
- Wild card filtering
- Create a list of variety of hashes e.g. MD5, SHA1, SHA256 etc.
- Shows output in clear GUI with grid and odd/ even row marking
- Can save output to variety of file types e.g. Tad Delimited, CSV, XML etc.

> HashMyFiles is a small utility that allows you to generate unique file identifiers (hashes) using a variety of different popular tools. File hashes can be submitted easily via the tool to VirusTotal for malware analysis.
>
> Formats supported include CRC32, MD5, SHA1, 256, 384 and 512. The various hashing information can be saved to a report (text/html/xml) that includes name, path, dates, file size, version, and other info.

Detailed Evaluation by someone:
http://www.mnhs.org/preserve/records/legislativerecords/carol/docs_pdfs/HashMyFilesEvaluation.pdf

Screenshot from the Portable Freeware Collection - http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=1535
[image: Screenshot from the Portable Freeware Collection]

They have a huge bunch of amazing tools at NirSoft - First toolset that I put on a new machine.

NirSoft's "SearchMyFiles" Apps has an amazing 'in-built' duplicates checker.